# Magento2 sort Cart items with Name

Tags: magento2, cart, items

I am working on of Mageto2.4.0 projects and currenly there is requirement to sort cart items with name e.g

suppose that we have some items in cart "Argus All-Weather Tank" ,"Hero Hoodie" ,"Fusion Backpack" .....

in which there are some configurable products in cart .

Now we have added some items as per below screenshot:

[image]

We want to display Hero Hoodies together and  "Argus All-Weather Tank" together.Means if products with same name display together.

Anyone have any idea please share me.

Answer (score 0):

I see in template:

vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\cart\form.phtml

It show Cart Items in foreach line 41->43

```
         <?php foreach ($block->getItems() as $_item) :?>
            <?= $block->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
```

We can debug in $block->getItems(), i see it call collection in file:

vendor\magento\module-checkout\Block\Cart\Grid.php

Function getItemsForGrid()

Then we sort order collection in this function